# How to specify DateTimeOffset precision with Linq-to-Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, database-partitioning

I have a VS2010 project with Linq-to-SQL classes generated from the SQL 2008 database. The concerning table has a special Created column, this colum has the type datetimeoffset(3) and is used as the **partioning**  key on a daily basis:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tableA](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Created] [datetimeoffset](3) NOT NULL,
    [A] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_TableA] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Created] ASC,
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) on partScheme_Daily_OnCreatedDate (Created)
) on partScheme_Daily_OnCreatedDate (Created)
```

The generated linq-to-SQL code for this column show DateTimeOffset as its type.

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.TableA")]
public partial class TableA : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private static PropertyChangingEventArgs emptyChangingEventArgs = new PropertyChangingEventArgs(String.Empty);
    private int _Id;
    private System.DateTimeOffset _Created;

    etc
```

I can create and execute a linq-to-sql query based on this generated classes.

```
var query = db.TableA.Where(pt => pt.Created >= (DateTimeOffset) startTime && pt.Created <= endTime
```

This translates to a correct SQL query, but the type on SQL side DateTimeOffset(7). The database therefore does not use the optimal partition elimination and accesses all partitions. If I change the type DateTimeOffset(3) based on captured SQL query and execute in SSMS it will use partition elimination.

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (10001) [t0].[Id], [t0].[Created], 
FROM [dbo].[TableA] AS [t0]
WHERE ([t0].[Created] >= @p0) AND ([t0].[Created] <= @p1) 
ORDER BY [t0].[Created] DESC',N'@p0 datetimeoffset(3),@p1 datetimeoffset(3)',@p0='2015-02-27 23:00:00 +00:00',@p1='2015-03-03 22:59:59 +00:00'
```

So how to get optimal partition elimination? In my example I would need access at most 2 partitions.

I thought of creating a stored procedure, but that would mean that I loose my flexibility of changing the query easily within c# code. 
Another solution would be changing the SQL type of the Created column into DateTimeOffset(7). But the disadvantage of that would be storing redundant precision data which I actually do not have.

I would like to hear other possibilities, either by instructing linq-to-sql generating DateTimeOffset(3) as a SQL variable type or an another way to make the partition elimination efficient.

PS: I have simplified the table definition and queries for short problem definition.

Comment: .Net uses a scale of 7, you want to use 3... compromise... ignore the question, look at their solution... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510384/how-do-i-stop-the-datetimeoffset-scale-from-causing-a-changeconflictexception-in

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTimeOffset.ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351892.aspx) formatting as you desire.

```
DateTimeOffset outputDate = new DateTimeOffset(2007, 11, 1, 9, 0, 0, 
                                 new TimeSpan(-7, 0, 0)); 
string format = "dddd, MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz";

// Output date and time using custom format specification
Console.WriteLine(outputDate.ToString(format, null as DateTimeFormatInfo));
Console.WriteLine(outputDate.ToString(format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
Console.WriteLine(outputDate.ToString(format, 
                                  new CultureInfo("fr-FR")));
Console.WriteLine(outputDate.ToString(format, 
                                  new CultureInfo("es-ES")));
// The example displays the following output to the console: 
//    Thursday, Nov 01 2007 09:00:00 -07:00 
//    Thursday, Nov 01 2007 09:00:00 -07:00 
//    jeudi, nov. 01 2007 09:00:00 -07:00 
//    jueves, nov 01 2007 09:00:00 -07:00
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know how to get rid of the dotnet precision. But what I would like to see is a way for linq-to-sql translating dotnet DateTimeOffset to sql DateTimeOffset(3) instead of DateTimeOffset(7).

Comment: @Ako Do you have a DBML file? This is a bit of overkill but have you looked into creating a custom type map? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc716764%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will check it out. The type in DBML is straigt forward: 
      <Column Name="Id" Type="System.Int32" DbType="Int NOT NULL IDENTITY" IsPrimaryKey="true" IsDbGenerated="true" CanBeNull="false" />
      <Column Name="Created" Type="System.DateTimeOffset" DbType="DateTimeOffset NOT NULL" IsPrimaryKey="true" CanBeNull="false" />